# SimpleXMLElement::xpath: extracting-data from osm xml file with php

Tags: php, xpath

i know little php but i am no expert here... - unfortunatley... so this question needs your advice: I tried to extract some data from an .Osm File. -.-you can run a demo-command here at overpass turbo i want to store the data in a database - (or at least in an excel-file)

```
> /* This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard. The original
> search was: “hospital in rome”
> */ [out:json][timeout:25]; // fetch area “” to search in {{geocodeArea:rome}}->.searchArea; // gather results (   // query part
> for:rome “hospital”   node["amenity"="hospital"](area.searchArea);  
> way["amenity"="hospital"](area.searchArea);  
> relation["amenity"="hospital"](area.searchArea); ); // print results
> out body;
> >; out skel qt;
```

So I have - within an amount of xml-data - something like this:

> "tags": {
>       "addr:city": "Barcelona",
>       "addr:housenumber": "1",
>       "addr:postcode": "08022",
>       "addr:street": "Carrer de Torras i Pujalt",
>       "amenity": "hospital",
>       "contact:email": "info@clinicasagradafamilia.com",
>       "contact:fax": "+34 932124050",
>       "contact:phone": "+34 932122300",
>       "contact:website": "http://csf.com.es/",
>       "name": "Cliníca Sagrada Família"   }

So, the question is this: how can store all those values I tried to make some kind of foreach without sucess. And definitely I don't know why is suposse we have one Iteration that get all the values and why is not possible to store together.

Well i heard about that we can use SimpleXMLElement::xpath here to get all the values and the corresponding values. For example :

```
> $raw = <<<EOF <root> {   "type": "node",   "id": 583257940,   "lat":
> 41.4134446,   "lon": 2.1426945,   "tags": {
>     "amenity": "hospital",
>     "emergency": "yes",
>     "name": "Clinica Delfos"   } }, {   "type": "node",   "id": 618312181,   "lat": 41.4138593,   "lon": 2.1970778,   "tags": {
>     "addr:city": "Barcelona",
>     "addr:housenumber": "211",
>     "addr:postcode": "08020",
>     "addr:street": "Carrer de Fluvià",
>     "amenity": "hospital",
>     "health_facility:type": "health_centre",
>     "medical_system:western": "yes",
>     "name": "CAP Sant Martí",
>     "phone": "+93 307 07 66"   } }, {   "type": "node",   "id": 876348001,   "lat": 41.3841883,   "lon": 2.1952253,   "tags": {
>     "amenity": "hospital",
>     "emergency": "yes",
>     "name": "Hospital del Mar",
>     "website": "http://www.parcdesalutmar.cat/hospitals/hospital-del-mar/index.html",
>     "wheelchair": "yes"   } },   
> 
> </root> EOF; $xml = simplexml_load_string($raw);
> 
> foreach($xml->xpath("//way") AS $way){
>     $via = $way->xpath("tag[@k='name']/@v")[0];
>     foreach($way->nd AS $nd){
>         $idnode = $nd["ref"];
>         echo $idnode .", ". $via  ."<br>";
>     } }
```

**question**: how to use SimpleXMLElement::xpath here?

xpath-approach that may help here:

i need to select all the data from above:

```
>   "tags": {
>     "addr:city": "Barcelona",
>     "addr:housenumber": "1",
>     "addr:postcode": "08022",
>     "addr:street": "Carrer de Torras i Pujalt",
>     "amenity": "hospital",
>     "contact:email": "info@clinicasagradafamilia.com",
>     "contact:fax": "+34 932124050",
>     "contact:phone": "+34 932122300",
>     "contact:website": "http://csf.com.es/",
>     "name": "Cliníca Sagrada Família"   }
```

That means that i have to  selects all above mentioned elements anywhere in the XML document.

tag[@k='name'] selects  child of current context node having k attribute value equal name. Then from that , /@v returns v attribute.

Finallyi have to getthe following dataset:

```
>   "tags": {
>     "addr:city": "Barcelona",


 "addr:housenumber": "1",
    "addr:postcode": "08022",
    "addr:street": "Carrer de Torras i Pujalt",
    "amenity": "hospital",
    "contact:email": "info@clinicasagradafamilia.com",
    "contact:fax": "+34 932124050",
    "contact:phone": "+34 932122300",
    "contact:website": "http://csf.com.es/",
    "name": "Cliníca Sagrada Família"   }
```

btw - you can run a demo-command here at overpass turbo

then you get lots of results....
question: how to store those results in either excel or mysql?

i really love to hear from you

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> "tags": { "addr:city": "Barcelona", "addr:housenumber": "1", 
>  "addr:postcode": "08022", "addr:street": "Carrer de Torras i Pujalt", 
>  "amenity": "hospital", "contact:email": "info@clinicasagradafamilia.com", 
>  "contact:fax": "+34 932124050", "contact:phone": "+34 932122300", 
>  "contact:website": "http://csf.com.es/", "name": "Cliníca Sagrada Família" }
> ```

and:

> question: how to use SimpleXMLElement::xpath here?

XPath is for XML. This is text data, looks like structured as JSON. While XPath 3.1 has functions to deal with JSON-structured data, it is not supported by PHP through their XPath processor.

> That means that i have to selects all above mentioned elements anywhere in the XML document.

There was only one element, `<root>`, in your example PHP code. You can select that with the xpath `/root` but it won't help you further, you will still have the unstructured JSON-as-a-string.

Instead, [check out `json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), it is meant to parse JSON and turn it into a PHP variable. The page shows a couple of examples on how to do just this.